# UICollectionViewCell not finding views from Nib

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView, in which I am using custom cells. I am registering the cells in viewDidLoad as so:

```
self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "IntroCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "IntroCell")
```

And setting them up in cellForItemAt:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell:IntroCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! IntroCell
    cell.refresh(cell: self.introScreens[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

IntroCell looks like this:

```
class IntroCell : UICollectionViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var subtitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    public func refresh(cell : IntroCellModel) {
        self.image.image = cell.image
        self.title.text = cell.title
        self.subtitle.text = cell.subtitle
    }

}
```

But whenever I run, I get this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Because the views in IntroCell are nil. Here is a screenshot of everything set up in IB.
[image]

Comment: Triple check that `reuseIdentifier` is right.

Comment: what is introScreens ? and what is your are passing to your xib class ? you have to check the cells in introScreens Array, they are somehow nil .

Comment: I'm a moron @shallowThought. Thank you.